# Intermittent: XP & OS X can't access file share / printer on Windows 7 workgroup server

Tags: windows-7, macos, file-sharing, network-printer

*(Just documenting my experience for the benefit of the community / Google searchers experiencing the same issue.)*

**Problem:**

In my house, I had a Windows XP computer that shared a **printer** and some **shared folders** with the rest of the computers on the network using a **Windows workgroup** (i.e. *not on a Windows domain; no Windows Server present on the home network.*)

Other client computers in the home ran Windows XP, Windows 7, and Mac OS X Snow Leopard.  Each client computer on the home network had identical username and password credentials set up to facilitate network sharing.

That all worked great.  Then, over the holidays, I repaved the Windows XP computer that hosts the printer and shared folders by installing a fresh copy of Windows 7 Professional (x64).  That's where the trouble began.

I started noticing a few days later that intermittently, the Windows XP and Mac OS X clients on the network were **unable to print to the shared printer**, and **unable to access the shared folders** offered by the Windows 7 computer.  However, the other Windows 7 client computer had no problem printing or accessing the shares, *even when the XP and OS X machines couldn't.*

Rebooting the client machines did not help.  Whereas, **rebooting the Windows 7 computer hosting the printer and shared folders would make everything work again.**  However, after some time passed, the failures would recur.

What was the problem?  I'll answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Windows 7 workgroup server hosting the printer and file shares, I started looking through the Windows event logs.  In the **System** event log, I found some Error log entries that read as follows:

> **"The server was unable to allocate
>   from the system nonpaged pool because
>   the server reached the configured
>   limit for nonpaged pool
>   allocations."**
>
> Log Name: System
>   Source: srv
>   Event ID: 2017
>   [...]

That struck me as odd, but it was something to go on.  After some searching with Google, I was led to the following thread at HardForum.com: **[Vista : unable to allocate from nonpaged pool = No network shares](http://www.hardforum.com/showthread.php?p=1032714322)**.

The solution/workaround I ended up implementing was found in that thread, in the post by user [Toytown](http://www.hardforum.com/member.php?u=99355) dated 07-06-2008, 07:23 AM.  Excerpt:

> After changing the NIC and going
>   through a bunch of reg settings, i
>   finally found the solution. It appears
>   that Vista uses SMB2 for networking
>   and its obviously buggy in certain
>   circumstances. Disabling it and
>   forcing SMB1 (pre vista networking)
>   fixes the problem and finally all my
>   machines are able to connect to the
>   Vista shares even after days of use.
>   The Bug in SMB2 reports the EVENTID
>   2017 into your eventlogs, complaining
>   that there is not enough nonpaged pool
>   memory left, however this is not the
>   case as taskmanager shows there is
>   easily enough and also that no
>   process's on the host machine are
>   leaking any nonpaged pool memory at
>   any point.
>
> So the fix is, either
>
> Download the reg file [here](http://www.rpgmerchants.com/SMB2-OFF.reg) and run it
>   on your Vista system. Restart your
>   computer and fixed.
>
> Or
>
> Open regedit goto HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
>   ->SYSTEM ->CurrentControlSet ->Services ->LanmanServer -> Parameters. Then click createkey and
>   create a DWORD with the name SMB2. The
>   value should automatically be set as
>   0, which is correct to turn it off.
>   Restart computer and fixed.
>
> To remove the fix and reenabled SMB2
>   simply remove the DWORD from the place
>   above in the registry.

---

Note:  It appears the issue has been around for quite some time, and I avoided it previously only because I skipped upgrading to Vista on the computer sharing the printer and file shares.  I'm surprised Microsoft hadn't fully addressed this issue for Windows 7 RTM.

Anyway, I hope that if you've found this page that this helps you solve your problem.

**If anybody else has anything to add related to this issue, please feel free to add another answer.**